# Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined Error

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Hello I am kind of new in VB and I am trying to control different pivot tables with a combobox, but when I try to do so I receieve the same error that says: "Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined Error". This is the code that I am using. Could someone help me to solve this issue?

```
Sub SwitchMarkets()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Market").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Market").CurrentPage = _
    Worksheets("Using Combo Box Controls").Range(“O5”).Value
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Market").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Market").CurrentPage = _
    Worksheets("Using Combo Box Controls").Range(“O5”).Value
End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You have tagged your question with vb.net, but the code looks like excel-vba. If you are using Visual Basic for Application (VBA) in Excel rather than Visual Basic in Visual Studio, please edit your question to use the correct tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, that error code is one of the least helpful in Excel, as it's caused by so many different things. I would check that each of your objects exists and can be manipulated in the way that you're trying to, e.g. is there a PivotTable on the Active sheet, and is it called `PivotTable1`? Does it have a field called `Market`? Does the worksheet `Using Combo Box Controls` exist and is there a valid value in cell `O5`? And so on.

Comment: Also, identify which of these statements is throwing the error - that will help limit the objects you have to verify. Usually in code I'm running a lot, I never assume the existence of an object, and always build in a test first to see that it exists _before_ trying to use it.

Comment: Are these pivot tables actually on the same sheet?  Using `ActiveSheet` for both without switching the sheet will require they are on the same sheet.  I also agree with @MarkWickett about the need to report which lines fails and if these objects all exist.

Comment: One thing I noticed is this line `Worksheets("Using Combo Box Controls").Range(“O5”).Value` The quotation marks around the `O5` are different quotation marks. If this is the line it is failing at change them to be normal quotation marks

Comment: Thanks @Sam you just save my life, it was what you say about the quotation marks!! I think they were in another format I don;t know why, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'll put it as an answer so others can see.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes around the `05` are different. change

`Worksheets("Using Combo Box Controls").Range(“O5”).Value`

to `Worksheets("Using Combo Box Controls").Range("O5").Value`